# Files in shared Google Drive not appearing in ArcGIS Online 'Add Item from Cloud Drive'

Tags: arcgis-online, google-drive, google-sheets

I am trying to add a Google Sheet to ArcGIS Online through the 'Add item from cloud drive' option as per https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022290.  It works pretty well aside from the fact that I can't see the files on the shared organizational Google Drive.  That is where the Google Sheet is that I want to bring into AGOL.  A colleague manages that sheet, so I can't move it to my personal Google Drive (where AGOL apparently has no issue seeing it).  The only files showing up through the 'add item from cloud drive' option are those that are in the 'shared with me' tag - which is a super small subset from the shared google drive - not all files on the shared drive.  I asked the colleague to share the file again with me, and she did, but it still doesn't appear in 'shared with me' in Google or in the ArcGIS Online dialogue.  Suggestions?  I also tried adding this google sheet as a shortcut in my Google Drive, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Have you sync'd Google Drive after the sheet was shared so that a copy of it resides on your local hard drive?

Comment: Thank you Bjorn for your message.  I have synced the file to my hard drive.  It is still not found by ArcGIS Online.  It seems that AGOL should be able to bring in a live link to all of my Google Sheets, but that isn't happening.  Other thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I opened a ticket for a similar issue a couple weeks ago and yes, it turned out that data in a **Shared Drive cannot sync with AGO**L. We had to move it back out of the shared drive to re-create the feature service (unfortunately the original connection was corrupted when moved to the SD). Hope that helps.